# How can I install Viber desktop missing module?

Tags: flatpak

I installed viber desktop from flathub.
I ran the application on the terminal
but it didn't start because:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/Resources/QML/MainWindow.qml: module "adwaita" is not installed
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect(QWindow, ApplicationEngine): invalid nullptr parameter
```

How can I solve this problem?

I'm using elementary 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I am using elementaryOS 7 and found the file to change at this location:

```
/usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
```

The line should be:

```
Exec=env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" /opt/viber/Viber %u
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue reported and solved here https://github.com/flathub/com.viber.Viber/issues/53#issuecomment-1279836789. Basically add `env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""` to the launcher.

1. Open the Files app and click `Home` in the left side bar;
2. On the upper-right corner, click the cogwheel menu icon -> check `Hidden files` (you should now see some folders with a dot in front, find the one named .local)
3. Navigate to `.local/share/flatpak/app/com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable/active/export/share/applications`
4. Double click the `com.viber.Viber.desktop` file to open it in Code editor.
5. Look for the line starting with `Exec=`.
6. After the `=` sign, add `env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""` so it looks like `Exec=env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" /usr/bin/flatpak run --bra`
7. use Ctrl + S to save the file
8. Try starting Viber now from the Applications menu.

[image]

Comment: oh my God!      all this is Greek to me,   so I will have to do WITHOUT  Viber desktop on elementary...

Comment: I will add more details to the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with step-by-step instructions. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I'm wondering, though. The same software package, from flathub, on fedora worked flawlessly

Comment: Different distributions, different desktop environments. If you put QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE into google, you're gonna have a full day of reading :D

Comment: right click inside home folder DOES NOT HAVE Show hidden files option

Comment: Yes, that option is now in the cogwheel menu of the Files app. On the upper-right corner, click the cog wheel -> check Hidden files. You can also enable it with CTRL + H

Comment: after opening numerous folders in the HIDDEN  local/share/flatpak/app/  I was unable to find  the com.viber.Viber.desktop file ,  don't waste your time Vlad, I will use viber on fedora where the flathub viber-desktop  app works , without having to search a million files, with no result

Comment: Dear Vlad, I finally managed to find the notorious hidden file. I changed the exec line , so now it looks like this: (it is the fourth line)   Exec=/env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=viber com.viber.Viber                                          I restarted the computer but still viber doesn't work,

Comment: I also tried starting it on the terminal but, to no avail,    at the end it says:       QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/Resources/QML/MainWindow.qml: module "adwaita" is not installed
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect(QWindow, ApplicationEngine): invalid nullptr parameter

Comment: There should be no / after the = sign. Edit it to Exec=env , not Exec=/env

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Exec=env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=viber com.viber.Viber
Icon=com.viber.Viber
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;P2P;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/viber;
StartupWMClass=Viber
X-Flatpak=com.viber.Viber                                                                                                                           I corrected the Exec line still viber does not open

Comment: I   tried the terminal but     it didn't work...
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/Resources/QML/MainWindow.qml: module "adwaita" is not installed
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect(QWindow, ApplicationEngine): invalid nullptr parameter

Comment: I am at a loss my friend. I installed it again from flathub, edited the file with Exec=env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""  and it just works. Are you sure you;re editing the right file? It should be located in ~/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable/active/export/share/applications

Comment: Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Exec=env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=viber com.viber.Viber
Icon=com.viber.Viber
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;P2P;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/viber;
StartupWMClass=Viber
X-Flatpak=com.viber.Viber

Comment: It's crazy . The file is exactly the one you said. I edited it with the CODE app

Comment: I'm using   elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir x86_64